# Laravel return from controller and continue routing

Tags: laravel, router

I haven't found an answer whether it is possible to return from a Laravel controller back to routers and continue searching for another route. Or maybe, another approach would be useful to solve this:

The goal is to have blog articles with url following the domain name like this:

```
domain.com/url-of-blog-article
```

so, my route looks like this:

```
Route::get ('{articleUrl}', 'WEB\BlogController@showArticle');
```

However, if the article with the requested url doesn't exists, I would like to return back to the router and continue with searching another page. One solution might be to put this route to the end of the router. But, is there a way to return from the controller without a view?

Comment: Are you not storing articles in a database? Why would you need to search another page for an article?

Comment: Put your wildcard route as the last route in the file.

Comment: devk, this is what I did. I think it is the only solution.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Not searching another article, just another pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible. Moreover, even if it were, I wouldn't recommend it -- your application would waste time searching the database for an article that doesn't exist, and it would go against the router's convention of matching a single route for a given URL.

Comment: You are probably right. My goal was to put the article route before admin routes that are rarely called to speed things up. Anyway, putting it to the end of the router will do the job and seems to be the only solution.